# How do make a login function using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, authentication, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I am a first-year programming student and I was tasked to make a Login and Register program using Java Swing (Application Window) and BufferedReader+Writer. I am now able to write a username and password into a text file via BWriter, however I have no idea how to make the Login read the text file and only Login when the inputted username and password in their respected TextField matches the one I wrote into the text file. (For reference the text file looks like this after I wrote the supposed username and password from the Register portion: Redman, 1234)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Register {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField tfNewUser;
    private JTextField tfNewPass;
    
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Register window = new Register();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Register() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Register");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 286, 324);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("REGISTER ");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 250, 26);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        tfNewUser = new JTextField();
        tfNewUser.setBounds(117, 48, 143, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tfNewUser);
        tfNewUser.setColumns(10);
        
        tfNewPass = new JTextField();
        tfNewPass.setBounds(117, 79, 143, 20);
        tfNewPass.setColumns(10);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tfNewPass);
        
        JButton btnReg = new JButton("REGISTER");
        btnReg.setBounds(10, 110, 250, 23);
        btnReg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String regUser = tfNewUser.getText().toString();
            String regPass = tfNewPass.getText().toString();
            addReg(regUser, regPass);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnReg);
        
        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("UPDATE CREDENTIALS");
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                UpdateCreds newformu = new UpdateCreds();
                newformu.main(null);
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnUpdate.setBounds(10, 213, 250, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpdate);
        
        JButton btnReturn = new JButton("RETURN TO LOGIN");
        btnReturn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Login newform = new Login();
                newform.main(null);
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnReturn.setBounds(10, 142, 250, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnReturn);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New Username: ");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 48, 97, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1_1 = new JLabel("New Password: ");
        lblNewLabel_1_1.setBounds(10, 82, 97, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1_1);
        
        JButton btnDeleteAcc = new JButton("DELETE ACCOUNT");
        btnDeleteAcc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            deleteAcc();
            }
        });
        btnDeleteAcc.setBounds(10, 247, 250, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDeleteAcc);
        
        JLabel lblAccountSettings = new JLabel("ACCOUNT SETTINGS");
        lblAccountSettings.setBounds(10, 176, 250, 26);
        lblAccountSettings.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblAccountSettings.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblAccountSettings);
    }
    
    public void errorPane (String msg, String status) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, msg, status, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    public void succMess (String smsg, String status2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, smsg, status2, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    public void clearTF() {
        tfNewUser.setText("");
        tfNewPass.setText("");
    }
    public void addReg(String regUser, String regPass) {
        try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Creds", true));
        bw.write(regUser+", "+regPass);
        bw.flush();
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
        succMess ("Account registered!", "SUCCESS");
        clearTF();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            errorPane("There is a problem with the data. Please input new data.", "ERROR" );
        }
        }
    public void deleteAcc() {
        try {
        String record;
        String regUser = tfNewUser.getText().toString();
        File tempCred = new File("Creds_temp");
        File cred = new File ("Creds");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cred));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempCred));
        
        while((record = br.readLine())!=null) {
            if(record.contains(regUser))
                continue;
            
            bw.write(record);
            bw.flush();
            bw.newLine();
                
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
        
        cred.delete();
        tempCred.renameTo(cred);
        succMess ("Account Deleted!", "SUCCESS");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            errorPane("Cannot find account. Please register an account first.", "ERROR" );
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Hey there, please notice that JavaScript is **not** the same as Java. Could you include some code you have so far?

Comment: My bad; in terms of code will the one that I have for the Register part suffice? Because I literally have nothing in the Login portion. Also, how do I modify my question?

Comment: Sure. That works.

Comment: Done editing. Took me a while to find the edit button that's literally under the post lmao

Comment: Okay. Sorry, had to re-edit your post because the tag got switched back to JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, dunno how that happened you literally switched it back to Java  20 minutes ago

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from approaching this in a different way?  I wouldn't bother with Buffer APIs in this context unless you're doing it to learn the underlying layers through application.

Comment: I think it's fine? As long as the text written into the file is still the one being used for the login function, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that the login file only deals with the authentication...

1. Read the `.txt` file line by line (I'm using Java Scanner for convenience, but you could use FileReader or anything else as well)
2. Split each line by comma delimiters and store the data in a hash map
3. Compare whether the user input matches one

---

In `Login.java`:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Login {
  private HashMap<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();
  private String name;
  private String password;
  void readFile() {
    try {
      // read file
      File file = new File("passwords.txt"); // replace with file name!!
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
      // loop through each line inside the file being read
      while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = reader.nextLine();
        String[] user = str.split(", "); // user[0] = anything before ", " and user[1] = anything after ", "
        userData.put(user[0], user[1]); // store username and password
      }
      reader.close(); // remember to close the reader
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Something happened...");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public boolean loggedIn() {
    return password.equals(userData.get(name));
  }
  
  // constructor to execute on instance creation
  public Login(String name, String password) {
    // initialize data
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    readFile();
  }
}
```

And pretend your user data file (`passwords.txt`) looks something like:

```
Redman, 1234
Bob, $up3r-$ecur3
Rob, pls don't hack
```

Using the class is pretty easy:

```java
Login attempt = new Login(username, password); // replace with requested variables as string
boolean success = attempt.loggedIn();

if(success) {
  // logged in successfully
} else {
  // incorrect username or password!
}
```

*[Working (only login) example.](https://onlinegdb.com/zn_3aWRWE)*

Hope that helps you get somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, this will work as a method right? For something like a JButton?

Comment: Also for some reason, the catch in my earlier code doesn't catch exceptions, but istead only shows the JOptionPane from the method succMess. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @AliceCherry I'm not sure what you mean as it will work as a method. It's a class, so you create an instance and use it. Can you elaborate on what you mean by the error thing?

Comment: I see. I think I fixed the error thingy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AliceCherry great! If it answered your question would you kindly mark it as so? Thanks!

Comment: What I meant by as a method is if I will be able to implement this as something like a public void Login (), to attach to a JButton.

Comment: @AliceCherry you can just initialize the class and do whatever you want... I can't find the login section in your code?